# Adding images using Query Selector/Template

Tags: javascript, templates, dom, queryselector

I am trying to get some images to show up in HTML using the query selector method and the DOM, but I am having trouble. The rest of the code seems to be doing what it is supposed to, but the images are just not showing up. Anyone have any pointers?

```
const ol = document.querySelector("ol")
const movies = [
    {
        name: "1917",
        year: 2020,
        director: "Sam Mendes",
        image: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1917_%282019_film%29#/media/File:1917_(2019)_Film_Poster.jpeg"
    },
    {
        name: "Godzilla",
        year: 1954,
        director: "Ishirō Honda",
        image: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_%281954_film%29#/media/File:Gojira_1954_Japanese_poster.jpg"
    },
    {
        name: "The Thing",
        year: 1982,
        director: "John Carpenter",
        image: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91U8fI0EBdL._SL1500_.jpg"
    },
];

const template = movies.map (movies => `
<li>
    <p>Name: ${movies.name}</p>
    <p>Release date: ${movies.year}</p>
    <p>Director: ${movies.director}</p>
    <img src= ${movies.image}</img>
 </li>
`);

ol.innerHTML = template.join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using image tag. Try this

```
const template = movies.map(movie => `
<li>
    <p>Name: ${movie.name}</p>
    <p>Release date: ${movie.year}</p>
    <p>Director: ${movie.director}</p>
    <img src="${movie.image}" />
 </li>
`);

ol.innerHTML = template.join('');
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried playing with the syntax before but couldn't get it to do what I wanted. I tend to overthink these kinds of problems.